# How does the executable exe created by QT creator take debug info

Tags: qt, dump

My project setting is like this:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -MT
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -MT

QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE +=/MAP
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += /Zi
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE +=/debug /opt:ref
```

As follow the above settings, the pdb and dump file all can be generated, but if I debug the dump file in vs2017, it shows that the module's debug info doesn't have source info.
Does the executable file don't contain the debug info?

Comment: I can't really follow this question. PDB is MSVC's format to store debug information **outside** the executable file. That's what you get from the `/Zi` option. I'm not sure what "dump" file you're trying to debug.

Comment: I mean the core dump in windows, as we usually trouble crash problem through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the executable does not contain the debug information. That information is stored in the PDB file, which is loaded only by debug tools. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files?view=vs-2019) how to access additional files (such as EXE and PDB files) alongside a dump file.

It may also useful to setup up [symbol servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019) for PDB's from other DLL's in your dump.